# How to know which tag was checked out previously

Tags: git, revert, git-revert

In the list of tags like

> v001
>   v002
>   v003
>   v004
>   v005

I pulled new tag lets say `v006` by `git fetch --tags` and `git checkout v006`.

By mistake I failed to note which version was checked out (`git describe --tags`) before this new checkout. There seems to be error and I have to revert back to old tag. How do I know which tag was used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HEAD` reflog records each successful checkout along with the text "moving from (point A) to (point B)", e.g.:

```
$ git reflog
676699a HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from
        695326c489285ed5678ac04d58289bcb24019bb9 to tag2
695326c HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from master to tag1
```

In this case I started on `master` and then did `git checkout tag` followed by `git checkout tag2`.  (Note: I edited the output slightly to make this more suitable for posting.  If you have git set up to pipe through "less" you may have to scroll left/right in your window to see everything.)

The first output line (which I wrapped so that it's the third quoted line) has a raw SHA-1 because when you check out a reference that is not a branch (or, when you use `--detach` with a branch) you get a "detached HEAD", where the `HEAD` file records a raw commit SHA-1.  However, we can see from the next line that `695326c489285ed5678ac04d58289bcb24019bb9` is the SHA-1 for tag `tag1`.

---

Note: you say "There seems to be error and I have to revert back to old tag", and refer (via Stack Overflow tags) to <kbd>git-revert</kbd>.  However, these kinds of `git checkout` (by tag or SHA-1) are about *looking at* some other version (i.e., getting a specific version into your work directory).  The `git revert` command is about adding a *new* commit whose effect is to undo some *old* commit.

In general you only want to `git revert` if you are "on a branch" (as in, `git checkout master` or `git checkout develop` or some other branch name), and you discover that someone committed incorrect code to that branch, and need to "reverse apply" their previous change and make that a new commit (which you would then probably publish, either `git push` or make a pull request).  So it seems odd to rever to "reverting" when what you have been doing is looking at old versions.

Comment: `git reflog` showed me everything I needed to know... thanks you very much